# UI elements disappear when scaled while using low-res graphics in Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with PS1 style graphics (specifically 256×224), and I'm trying to apply the low-res effect to the UI, but this happens:[image]

It seems like at some point there's just a limit to how small I'm allowed to make the crosshairs, and I can't figure out any sort of way around it no matter what boxes I check. Any suggestions/workarounds? Thanks!